# Formatting JSON formatted text file in PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

So I got a HTML page with a button. When I click the button, a separate javascript file sends a GET request to my PHP file, expecting a JSON object in return. My PHP reads a JSON formatted text file and should convert it into a JSONObject and echo it out for my javascipt. I had some code working before, but it doesn't seem to do it anymore since I changed to a Ajax aproach instead of having everything in the same file. This is my code:

*readLog.php*

```
<?php
class test{

function clean($string){
    return json_decode(rtrim(trim($string),','),true);
}

function getLog(){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $logLines = file('../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log');
    $entries = array_map("clean",$logLines);
    $finalOutput = ['log'  => $entries];
    echo json_encode($logLines);

}
}
 ?>
```

My humid.log file looks like this:

```
{"date":"26/09/2016", "time":"22:40:46","temp":"16.0", "humidity":"71.0" }     
{"date":"26/09/2016", "time":"23:10:47","temp":"16.0", "humidity":"71.0" }
```

Now If I press my button, this is the response I get checking the console in my web browser:

Response:

```
["{\"date\":\"26\/09\/2016\", \"time\":\"22:40:46\",\"temp\":\"16.0\", \"humidity\":\"71.0\" }{\"date\":\"26\/09\/2016\", \"time\":\"23:10:47\",\"temp\":\"16.0\", \"humidity\":\"71.0\" }\n"]
```

JSON:

```
"{"date":"26/09/2016", "time":"22:40:46","temp":"16.0", "humidity":"71.0" }{"date":"26/09/2016", "time":"23:10:47","temp":"16.0", "humidity":"71.0" }\n"
```

obviously something is wrong with the formatting, but I don't know what. As I said, this code worked just fine when I had my php and HTML in the same file.

EDIT:

I have also tried formatting the JSON with something like this, but it just prints the brackets:

```
function getLog(){
    $text = file('../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log');
    $textRemoved ="["; //Add opening bracket.
    $textRemoved .= substr($text, 0, strlen($text)-1); (Remove last comma)
    $textRemoved .="]";//Add closing bracket
    $json = json_encode($textRemoved);
    echo $json;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML that contains the AJAX JS as well?

Comment: It looks like you are `json_encode()`ing `humid.log`, which is already JSON, and printing it (you are encoding already-encoded data). Although I should point out that the `humid.log` contents you posted above aren't valid JSON. If it's an array of objects, they should be separated with a comma and encapsulated with brackets (`[{obj_1}, {obj_2}]`).

Comment: I think part of the problem is also that you are encoding `$logLines` instead of `$entries` or `$finalOutput`.

Comment: Your code expects each JSON object in the file to be on a separate line. But you have two JSON objects on the same line.

Comment: I guess that must be a formatting error in the question, because otherwise you'd be getting errors, not incorrect output.

Comment: @bubelf: Change the `echo json_encode($logLines);` to `echo json_encode($entries);` and tell us what you are getting then.

Comment: If I do that, I just get null in the alert box.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve it myself. Basicly The formatting of the textfile was wrong and as some commentors said, I don't need to encode it if I am doing it myself. What I ended up doing was in my application that generates the log file to add comma after each row. Then in my PHP I added brackets and removed the last comma.

```
function getLog(){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $file = file_get_contents('../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log');
    $lengthOfFile = strlen($file)-2;
    $subFile = substr($file, 0, $lengthOfFile);
    $res ="[";
    $res .= $subFile;
    $res .="]";
    echo $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just jam two+ JSON strings togther. It's JSON, which means it HAS to be syntactically correct Javascript **CODE**. If you want to join two json strings together, you HAVE to decode them to a native data structure, join those structures together, then re-encode the new merged structure:

```
$temp1 = json_decode('{"foo":"bar"}', true);
$temp2 = json_decode('{"baz":"qux"}', true);

$new = array_merge($temp1, $temp2);
echo json_encode($new);
```

which will produce:

```
{"foo":"bar","baz":"qux"}
```

and remain valid JSON/Javascript.

Why? Consider that bare integers are valid json:

```
json_encode(42) -> 42
json_encode(123) -> 123
```

If you have two json-encoded integers and jam together, you get a "new" integer:

```
 42123
```

and on the receiving end, you'll be going "Ok, so where is the split between the two", because `4` and `2123` are just as valid as possible original values as `4212` and `3`.

Sending the two integers as distinct and SEPARATABLE values would require an array:

```
[42,123]
```